# Oracle - How to get a number from an object in a sql query?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this object:

```
    CREATE TYPE CarType AS OBJECT(
        price_id NUMBER,
        quantity NUMBER.
        MAP MEMBER FUNCTION get_price_id RETURN NUMBER
        );
```

and this table:

```
CREATE TABLE Cars(
   carid NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
   carinfo cartype,
   CONSTRAINT car_fk FOREIGN KEY(carinfo.price_id) REFERENCES prices(price_id)
);
```

and I want to get the carid,price_id from Cars table  with a sql query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must remember about aliasing your table and accessing columns with object type using alias, otherwise you will get `ORA-00904  invalid identifier` error.
This query will work:

```
SELECT C.CARID, C.CARINFO.PRICE_ID, C.CARINFO.QUANTITY FROM CARS C;
```

But this will not:

```
SELECT CARS.CARID, CARS.CARINFO.PRICE_ID, CARS.CARINFO.QUANTITY FROM CARS;
```